# ios change button title font when pressed

Tags: ios, button, fonts

i'm new on ios and i wonder if is it possible to change button's title font when it is pressed, i can change button's color when its highlighted as:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

is there anything like this to change button's font size, without writing button pressed methods.(i want to change font on highlighted state, so i'm not sure if buttonPressed method will work clearly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `titleLabel` property:

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
```

**EDIT**: You'll have to use it in the actions `UIControlEventTouchDown`, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`.

Comment: This will require writing a button pressed method. Though doing so is what I would recommend.

Comment: Yeah he'll have to change it to one font during touchdown and then change it back for all the up events.

Comment: Thanks, it worked by calling simple method that executes the line you wrote with forControlEvents

Answer (score 2):

If you are insistent upon not writing a button pressed method, you could try your luck with attributed strings. UIButton has the method

```
– setAttributedTitle:forState:
```

You can change the highlighted state to use a version of your string with the correct font that way.

You can learn more about attributed strings in [the Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html).

Yet another solution is to use custom images for your buttons. And use the method

```
– setImage:forState:
```

Comment: `setAttributedTitle:forState:` seems ideal. I tried to use it, starting with a mutable copy of button.currentAttributedTitle and adding the attribute NSFontAttributeName. But I can't figure out why button.currentAttributedTitle and [button attributedTitleForState:UIControlStateNormal] are always nil, even when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setTitle:@"Click Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```